# AWS SDK - S3 GeneratePreSignedURL method gives "X-Amz-Expires must be non-negative"

Tags: c#, amazon-s3

I'm using AWS SDK to access S3 bucket for READ and WRITE objects in C#. I was able to get it working in a .NET project according to the instructions followed in the documentation. I want to limit the public access to the bucket and provide an expiring public link to object.

I found out it could be done using `GeneratePreSignedURL` method. It gives a URL string in below format.

```
https://<BUCKET_NAME>.s3.<REGION>.amazonaws.com/<KEY>?X-Amz-Expires=-46077&X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=<GENERATED_CRED>&X-Amz-Date=20201122T071756Z&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Signature=<GENERATED_SIG>
```

I then place this URL in a browser window to check if it works as expected. The issue is Im getting an error saying `X-Amz-Expires must be non-negative`

Postman response :

```
<Error>
    <Code>AuthorizationQueryParametersError</Code>
    <Message>X-Amz-Expires must be non-negative</Message>
    <RequestId>3ZCYDRAH2W3MET8P</RequestId>
    <HostId>f9BnxF5xXJIkklXfwMPVCxFSJLIkPxijzElqqA3bEcbt7PqY/lhzm6rbQ8KFzICy3B1J/Stdvf8=</HostId>
</Error>
```

In the method that the SDK provides I provide a positive double value for the `expiration` value, so I'm not sure how the generated URL has a `X-Amz-Expires=-46077`. Any idea about this would be really helpful, thanks.

Comment: I can't find any references to `GetFilePublicURL`, is that a method you made? You should share some code of your attempt and also what expiration you used. It sounds like you're using an expiration in the past.

Comment: @Shoejep oops!! sorry its ```GeneratePreSignedURL```, I'll correct the question. Thanks for pointing it out..

```_s3Client.GeneratePreSignedURL(bucketName, key, DateTime.Now.Date, null);``` here is the code line that generates the URL.

Comment: @Shoejep I tried setting a value like 15 using ```DateTime.Now.AddMinute(15).Date``` to the line ```_s3Client.GeneratePreSignedURL(bucketName, key, DateTime.Now.Date, null);``` it didn't solve anything..

Comment: Using `DateTime.Now.AddMinute(15).Date` sounds like it might be your problem, `.Date` removes the time component of the DateTime. Just do `DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(15)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(15)` instead of `DateTime.Now.AddMinute(15).Date`.

`.Date` removes the time component of the DateTime

As described in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.date?view=net-5.0) for `.Date`

> A new object with the same date as this instance, and the time value set to 12:00:00 midnight (00:00:00).